# functions in javascript wrapped in parenthesis

Tags: javascript, iife

I am new to javascript and I might have dove into the deep end first. I have came across the following definition while reading design patterns in js. I don't understand the syntax used here, why is the "log" function definition in "()",

```
var log = (function() {
    var log = "";
    return {
        add: function(msg) { log += msg + "\n"; },
        show: function() { alert(log); log = ""; }
    }
})();
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). `log` is not a function, it ends up as a module, exporting two functions (`log.add` and `log.show`).

Comment: If you don't care about the return value, you can save a character with `!function(){/* code */}()`

Comment: Partly a duplicate, but this also involves the **module pattern**, which is not part of the other question/answers.

Comment: @royhowie: The module pattern is all about the return value :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the parenthesis, the right hand side of your assignment is a function expression, and log is assigned a reference to that (anonymous) function expression, allowing to call `log()` later.

If you include the parenthesis, the wrapped function turns into a self-invoking function expression (and is immediately executed), so `log` is assigned whatever this function call **returns**.

As someone else already stated, your code shows an example of the so-called **module pattern**. Read much more about it [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

Comment: Nitpick: in `log = function(...) { ... }`, the right hand side is already an expression - a function expression. It is not the parentheses that turn it into one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried to correct my answer accordingly. More about function declaration vs expression here: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand the syntax used here, why is the "log" function
>   definition in "()"

Its basically self executing anonymous function. There are several ways of writing such functions.

```js
(function() {
  alert('hi there');
})();

! function() {
  alert('hello');
}();

+ function() {
  alert('plus');
}();

- function() {
  alert('minus');
}();
```

Now such function can also return values:

```js
var msg = (function() {
  return 'hello';
})();

alert(msg);

var calc = (function() {
  return {
    add: function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    },
    sub: function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    }
  };
})();

alert(calc.add(4, 5));
```

Comment: The `(function(...) {...})(...)` is considered standard; `!` is used by some as a hack that saves a couple of characters; But `+` and `-` are *bad practices* (`if (true) return 1<newline>+function() { return 2 }()` returns an unexpected result - `3` instead of `1` that other methods would return).